# When running a program, is it correct to say "execute"?

Tags: word-usage

I don't want to be repeating "run" a program in a report I am writing.

Is it correct to say "execute a program" (with the same meaning)?

Otherwise, what are other ways to say "run a program"?

Comment: https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/execute  You have to scroll down a bit.

Comment: @JamesK Thanks! Does it sound natural? Is it usually used as much as "run"?

Comment: I think of executing is something the software does ("executing a command" rather than something you do.

Comment: It's hard to find references for the precise use of a word in a technical context. I'd be more likely to use "execute" for a program that runs quickly to perform a simple task (as in executing a shell command); if you're starting up a word processor or browser "launch" or "open" might be better.

Comment: @JamesK That definition indicates that *a computer* can execute code, not that a human user can.

Comment: I don't get what you mean.  Of course only computer can execute code, but they only do so when instructed, ultimately by a human.  When I say "I executed the program" we mean "I instructed a computer to execute the program", in the same way as we could use "run", etc.

Comment: @JamesK I mean I'm splitting the hair between verbs that mean computers actually doing the thing to the code, and humans instructing the computer to do the thing to the code. See my answer for more of what I mean.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, "execute" can be used in the same sense as "run" in this context, but it isn't a current usage anymore.

In many operating systems, like Windows and various types of DOS, files that the user can run have the extension ".exe", which stands for "executable", but these days, "execute" sounds more like something the computer does to the code, rather than what the user does.

More natural and current words with the meaning you're looking for include "**start**", "**open**" and "**launch**".